# Weird dynamic CSS class with "display: none" on WordPress blog

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

On my friends blog on 1 page there is weird (4 me) CSS class that is created  dynamically. Name is always something like [zsgqlex]

On my computer it happens on Chrome (works on Firefox), on another it happens on Firefox and works on Chrome :/

Any idea what is going on?

https://www.lessfear.pl/reklama

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's an attribute selector. So it selects all elements with the attribute [zsgqlex]. You can also use specific values for this selector as you can see in the example below.

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
}

[zsgqlex] {
  background-color: pink;
}

[zsgqlex="value"] {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div>no attribute</div>
<div zsgqlex>attribute without specified value</div>
<div zsgqlex="value">attribute with value</div>
<div zsgqlex="another value">attribute with another value not in the css</div>
```

Comment: But where does it come from? We don't use any custom styles. Maybe some plugin?

Comment: @MooKate — Maybe. Try turning plugins off until it goes away.

Comment: Thanks a lot, ill try :)

Comment: @MooKate Yeah it looks like some plugin is probably generating a random attribute name and use this to apply this `display: none;` style. It's impossible to know where it's coming from without seeing the code. As @Quentin said the best thing to do is to switch off all (style related) plugins and turn it on till you found the problem.